# Does the language of Regular Expressions need a push down automata to parse it?

Tags: formal-languages, parsers, regular-expressions, pushdown-automata

I want to convert a user entered regular expression into an NFA so that I can then run the NFA against a string for matching purposes. What is the minimum machine that can be used to parse regular expresssions?

I assume it must be a push down automaton because the presense of brackets means the need to count and a DFA/NFA cannot perform arbitrary counting. Is this assumption correct? For example, the expression a(bc*)d would require a PDA so that the sub-expression in brackets is handled correctly.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "parsing"? Do you mean checking if the input is really a regular expression or do you have a more complicated thing in mind, e.g. a machine outputting a description of the corresponding NFA? (if you are not sure if the input is really a regular expression and you need to check it then you need to be able to check that parenthesis are correct and that normally means using a stack.)

Comment: For a practical answer, you could look at the [Plan 9 Grep source for grep.y](http://swtch.com/usr/local/plan9/src/cmd/grep/grep.y).

Answer (score 10):

You are correct. It is easy to show that the syntax of regular expressions is not regular using [standard techniques](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular).

One possibility is to use a homomorphism (which $\mathrm{REG}$ is closed against) to get rid of all symbols but the parentheses, which leaves you with the [Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) which is well-known to be non-regular. If in doubt, use the Pumping lemma on $(^p)^p$.

That said, you probably do not want to code a PDA by hand. Consider using a parser generator like [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) or [byacc](http://invisible-island.net/byacc/byacc.html). If, on the other hand, you want to investigate the parsing of languages by programming parsers yourself, you should continue with other basic parsing algorithms such as [CYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK), [Earley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser), [recursive descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) and [LR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser).

Comment: thanks. writing code for these tasks creates a better understanding and is not intended to be as efficient as existing utilities like lex,yacc,bison etc.

Comment: @PhilWright: I see, nice! I edited in further pointers for this case.

Comment: I'd favour a hand-coded recursive descent parser for this one.

Comment: If writing a parser by hand for this, either recursive descent (after factoring and massaging) is an option, the LCC parser for C <http://sites.google.com/site/lccretargetablecompiler> has an interesting take for handling lots of operators. But perhaps easiest for hand-building is precedence parsing.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to read the Jukka's nice answer to the question "[Matching regular expressions using regular expressions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8604/matching-regular-expressions-using-regular-expressions)" on cstheory, too. An excerpt:

> For example, we can modify the standard notation as follows to obtain *"compressed" regular expressions*:
>
> - You are allowed to remove any prefix that consists of a sequence of ('s
> - You are allowed to remove any suffix that consists of a sequence of )'s
>
> That is, `((a|b)*c)de(f|g)` can be expressed in the "compressed" notation using, for example, any of the following forms: `a|b)*c)de(f|g` or `((a|b)*c)de(f|g` or `(a|b)*c)de(f|g)`.
>
> [...]
>
> The "compressed" notation (of a regular expression) is a regular language.

This is only a link to an interesting (according to me) "different view" on the regular expression language; as underlined in the comments below,
it is not useful for building a syntax tree. If you want to hand code your parser I'll suggest you this simple article on codeproject "[Writing-own-regular-expression-parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5412/Writing-own-regular-expression-parser)".

Comment: Jukka essentially removes the requirement that parentheses are balanced. I know of no instance where this is actually done, but it is worth remarking that by changing semantics, you can "simplify" syntax.

Comment: You (and Jukka) aren't parsing regexps, only recognizing them. “Yup, that's a (compressed) regexp.”